# Generics в Java. Компаратор

Tags: java

```
public class Node<E> {
    int x;
    Node l, r;
    public Node() {}
    public Node(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public boolean search(int x){//Поиск элемента, если есть возвращает true
        if(this.x == x) return true;
        else if(this.x > x && l != null) return l.search(x); //Если x > or < значения в узле и если узел не пуст
        else if(this.x < x && r != null) return r.search(x); //Вызываем search от узла
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Как правильно использовать generic и как в функции `search` использовать `comparator` для сравнения объектов не примитивных типов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот мой вариант решения вашей задачи:

```
 public boolean treeSearch(Node<E> x, E k) {
    int cmp;
    while (x != null && k != x.value) {
        cmp = compare(x.value, k);
        if (cmp > 0) {
            x = x.left;
        } else {
            x = x.right;
        }
    }
    return x != null;
}
```

Node - это тип обычного узла, x - узел с которого начинаем поиск. k - элемент, который ищем.

```
  private int compare(E val1, E val2) {
    return ((Comparable<? super E>) val1).compareTo(val2);
}
```

*Дополнительная* *информация* (*пример использования метода compare с обобщениями*)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

E - здесь обозначает по сути параметр типа, который при создании  будет заменён реальным типом, к примеру, как на скриншоте, при создании UseMyReal. В main при объявлении экземпляра класса с названием myReal мы определяем,что дженерик E будет заменён на тип Integer. Соответственно в этой реализации метод compare должен будет принимать (Integer val1, Integer val2).

Comment: Не подскажите как сравнить переменную типа E с нулем?

Comment: например T x; compare(x, 0); можно ли типо этого что-то сделать?

Comment: Артем, не очень понимаю что вы хотите. Забыл написать, что метод compare в данной процедуре будет возвращает только 1, 0, -1. т.e если x.value < k, compare вернёт -1, если x.value > k  compare вернёт 1, если равно то 0. Почитайте Шилдта справочник, там есть раздел про компараторы, много всего интересного

Comment: В том виде, в котором сейчас метод, он способен сравнивать  (x.value, 0), но не (x.value, null) или (null, x) Если у вас есть ещё вопросы задавайте

Comment: Если доп вопросов нет, не забывайте отмечать ответы, как верные.

Comment: я попытался сравнить compare(x.value, 0) пишет Wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'int' required: 'T'

Comment: Всё работает, у вас проблема в реализации. Вы в метод сравнения compare, передаёте второй аргумент не того типа, который определили. Передаёте 'int', а ожидается, что передадите 'T'. Проследите за тем что бы метод compare принимал параметры типа T.

Comment: Не понимаю как это сделать, если мне нужно сравнить переменную типа T с нулем.

Comment: @Артем, я написал доп информацию к ответу. Надеюсь эта информация вам поможет.